# mysql nested count - how?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

Here's the initial query:
`SELECT COUNT(column) FROM table GROUP BY column;`
This gives me something like the following:
`COUNT(column)`
`2`
`4`
`1`
`1`
`3`
etc.
BUT I need to to count all of those together in one number! How could I do that? `COUNT(COUNT(column))` throws an error: "Invalid use of group function".
P.S. this is not used in any program, if it was, it would be trivial to count them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the group by:

```
select count(column) from table;
```

if you need distinct columns:

```
select count(distinct column) from table; -- might not work in mysql
```

or:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct column from table) as columns;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in mysql: SELECT COUNT(distinct column) FROM table